# System.Collection.Generic.IEnummerable<string> == string

Tags: c#

I get a user from the DB and the user has a list of accounts.
And I need to check if the name of one account is equal to a string.
so I selected all accounts and then the names:

```
var accounts = user.Select(u=> u.Accounts.Select(a => a.Name)).ToList();
```

And then I check one name after an other:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= accounts.Count(); i++)
{
     if (accounts[i] == mandant)
         return true;
}
```

but type of `mandant` = `string`
and type of `accounts[i]` = `System.Collections.Generic.IEnummerable<string>`

How to check if that is equal?

Comment: He said `IEnumerable<string>` but not in code delimiters so the formatter stripped it like it was raw HTML.

Comment: @280Z28 I see, how stupid of me :p

Comment: What is the type of the Name attribute you are selecting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to flatten `Account` first by using `SelectMany`, then use `Any` to check:

```
if (users.SelectMany(u => u.Accounts).Any(a => a.Name == mandant))
{
}
```

Or use double `Any` to check:

```
if (users.Any(u => u.Accounts.Any(a => a.Name == mandant)))
{
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but the first doesn't work. But the second worked for me. Thanks a lot.